# Importing a typescript class from another file

Tags: typescript

Just starting out with typescript and I'm trying to simply import a class from one file to another, sounds simple.. but I keep getting the error:

> renderer.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

I've got my main entry file app.ts:

```
import {Renderer} from '../ts/renderer.ts';
var renderer = new Renderer();
console.log("-- Start --");
```

And I have this in my renderer.ts:

```
export class Renderer {  
}
```

I'm using Gulp to compile my typescript into js. Here is what I'm using:

```
var gulp    = require('gulp');
var tsc     = require('gulp-typescript-compiler');
var $       = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('ts-compile', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('ts/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(tsc({
        module: "commonjs",
        target: "es5",
        moduleResolution: "node",
        sourcemap: true,
        logErrors: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});

gulp.task('js-compile', function () {
    return gulp
        .src(['app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.concat('main.js'))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});

gulp.task('watch-all', function() {
    gulp.watch(['ts/**/*.ts'], ['ts-compile']);
    gulp.watch(['app/**/*.js'], ['js-compile']);
});
```

Anyone have any ideas why it's throwing that error? My app.ts file doesn't seem to compile due to the "import" line which may explain the error, but that looks right to me.

Comment: Are you getting this error at compile time or at runtime? If at runtime is it in a browser or NodeJS?

Comment: I'm running it through a browser. I get the error at runtime in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use browserify in order to use CommonJS modules in the browser.

Luckily you are most of the way there. You will just need to replace the `gulp-typescript-compiler` with [gulp-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify) and [tsify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify) plugin.

Here is an example Gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var tsify = require('tsify');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

var watchedBrowserify = watchify(browserify({
    basedir: '.',
    debug: true,
    entries: "src/main.ts",
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {}
}).plugin(tsify));

gulp.task('ts:watch', bundle);

function bundle() {
    return watchedBrowserify
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}

gulp.task('default', ['ts:watch']);
watchedBrowserify.on('update', bundle);
watchedBrowserify.on('log', gutil.log);
```